# Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0)

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I get this error when trying to run the flutter project on the android emulator.
Launching lib\main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download gradle.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0)
> > Could not get resource 
> 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.1.0/gradle-4.1.0.jar'.
> > Read timed out

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 57s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**build.gradle :**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to update your gradle-wrapper.properties file and check this:

`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-all.zip`

Kindly update this 7.0.2-all version to match according to version 4 that you are using.

Update your build.gradle version as well:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried this but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

in  outdated projects, in android/build.gradle use belowe codes:

```
repositories {
//        google()
//        mavenCentral()
     maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```